# can't read my json file using angular http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I have my json data when i try to read my json data from a json file using http service which angular provided it doesn't work but when i just put it in a scrope direct variable it works.

i tried using this  code to read my json file :

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

//    WE USE SCOPE variable TO PASS THINGS FROM THE JAVASCRIPT AND VISE VERSA

//    ITS LIKE AN OBJECT 

//    GET FOR ME THE DATa FROM THIS FILE CALLED data.json AND THEN ITS SUCESS HA SO DO A FUNCTION GET THE DATA 
 $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){ 
//     GRAB THE DATA AND PUT IT IN THAT VARIABLE 
     var vm = this;
    vm.data = data;



 });  
}]);
```

but when i use it like that it work perfectly :

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.data = [{ 
     errors:
   [ { type: 'ActionView::Temp',

       message: 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]',
       backtrace: [Object] },
     { type: 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError',

       message: 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]',
       backtrace: [Object] } ],
  context:

   {
       rootDirectory: '/app',
     environment: 'production',
     hostname: 'af71d84',
     time: '2016-10-20 08:41:04 aaaaaaaaaaaC',
     os: 'x86_64-linux',
     language: 'ruby/2.3.0',
     notifier:
      { name: 'airbrake-ruby',
        version: '1.6.0',
        url: 'https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby' },
     url: 'https://carzar.herokuapp.com/cars/58079b9e918120003d678ef/quotes/580759cae918120003d678f0',
     userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
     version: 'Rails/5.0.0.1',
     component: 'quotes',
     action: 'show' },
  environment:

   {
       httpMethod: 'GET',
     referer: null,
     headers:
      { HTTP_VERSION: 'HTTP/1.1',
        HTTP_HOST: 'carzar.herokuapp.com',
        HTTP_CONNECTION: 'close',
        HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: '1',
        HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
        HTTP_ACCEPT: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        HTTP_COOKIE: '_hjIncludedInSample=1; _ga=GA1.3.1023727724.1471250148; _website_session=Uzl4cVdsbzk4dEkxK0E5VFJxdWhHQmNJQVpHenNCdThuYkRFUERPNFhJNktzVHpKMlM0NzJlSEZFQmFGTUFwTXFLMDFySVh0Tnl1MjhEZzBrcUF0YTJmdXVzUE1ac3ltNG0ySDkxNlpIN2J2SDNQdmJYL0ZFS2Y3U1N0SEdOZTB1NnNOZGlrVm95SHdZSy93cGtCYW5nPT0tLW9zSERCSWgyNGdiMGw5VnZ0eTExR2c9PQ%3D%3D--0eecd3ec3784b2e82c65a09c677eac1c1482bfda',
        HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID: '',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: '196.22.246.146',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO: 'https',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT: '443',
        HTTP_VIA: '1.1 vegur',
        HTTP_CONNECT_TIME: '0',
        HTTP_X_REQUEST_START: '1476952864670',
        HTTP_TOTAL_ROUTE_TIME: '0' } },
  session:
   { 
       session_id: '29e60f46d03a58702d3aada65c860482',
     _csrf_token: 'uF90eNX/nyVS72rEgM9ZNmGOJj4ad7gb35SKM941egs=' },
  params:

   { controller: 'quotes',
     action: 'show',
     car_id: '58079b9e918120003d678ef',
     id: '580759cae918120003d678f0',
     time: '2016-10-20T08:41:05.111Z' },
        name: "first",
        thingy: 1
},
               { 
     errors:
   [ { type: 'ActionView::Template::Error',

       message: 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]',
       backtrace: [Object] },
     { type: 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError',

       message: 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]',
       backtrace: [Object] } ],
  context:

   {
       rootDirectory: '/app',
     environment: 'production',
     hostname: 'af71d84a-f06d-4d29-8197-600f5c1ebffa',
     time: '2016-10-20 08:41:04 UTC',
     os: 'x86_64-linux',
     language: 'ruby/2.3.0',
     notifier:
      { name: 'airbrake-ruby',
        version: '1.6.0',
        url: 'https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby' },
     url: 'https://carzar.herokuapp.com/cars/58079b9e918120003d678ef/quotes/580759cae918120003d678f0',
     userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
     version: 'Rails/5.0.0.1',
     component: 'quotes',
     action: 'show' },
  environment:

   {
       httpMethod: 'GET',
     referer: null,
     headers:
      { HTTP_VERSION: 'HTTP/1.1',
        HTTP_HOST: 'carzar.herokuapp.com',
        HTTP_CONNECTION: 'close',
        HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: '1',
        HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
        HTTP_ACCEPT: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        HTTP_COOKIE: '_hjIncludedInSample=1; _ga=GA1.3.1023727724.1471250148; _website_session=Uzl4cVdsbzk4dEkxK0E5VFJxdWhHQmNJQVpHenNCdThuYkRFUERPNFhJNktzVHpKMlM0NzJlSEZFQmFGTUFwTXFLMDFySVh0F0YTJmdXVzUE1ac3ltNG0ySDkxNlpIN2J2SDNQdmJYL0ZFS2Y3U1N0SEdOZTB1NnNOZGlrVm95SHdZSy93cGtCYW5nPT0tLW9zSERCSWgyNGdiMGw5VnZ0eTExR2c9PQ%3D%3D--0eecd3ec3784b2e82c65a09c677eac1c1482bfda',
        HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID: 'c270acca-988f-4f14--2ce4c8abacce',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: '196.22.246.146',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO: 'https',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT: '443',
        HTTP_VIA: '1.1 vegur',
        HTTP_CONNECT_TIME: '0',
        HTTP_X_REQUEST_START: '1476952864670',
        HTTP_TOTAL_ROUTE_TIME: '0' } },
  session:
   { 
       session_id: '29e60f46d03a58702d3aada65c860482',
     _csrf_token: 'uF90eNX/nyVS72rEgM9ZNmGOJj4ad7gb35SKM941egs=' },
  params:

   { controller: 'quotes',
     action: 'show',
     car_id: '58079b9e918120003d678ef',
     id: '',
     time: '2016-10-20T08:41:05.111Z' },
        name: "second",
        thingy: 2
}

               ,{ 
     errors:
   [ { type: 'ActionView::Template::Error',

       message: 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]',
       backtrace: [Object] },
     { type: 'ActionController::UrlGenerationError',

       message: 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]',
       backtrace: [Object] } ],
  context:

   {
       rootDirectory: '/app',
     environment: 'production',
     hostname: 'af71d84a-f06d-4d29-8197-600f5c1ebffa',
     time: '2016-10-20 08:41:04 UTC',
     os: 'x86_64-linux',
     language: 'ruby/2.3.0',
     notifier:
      { name: 'airbrake-ruby',
        version: '1.6.0',
        url: 'https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby' },
     url: 'https://carzar.herokuapp.com/cars/58079b9e918120003d678ef/quotes/580759cae918120003d678f0',
     userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
     version: 'Rails/5.0.0.1',
     component: 'quotes',
     action: 'show' },
  environment:

   {
       httpMethod: 'GET',
     referer: null,
     headers:
      { HTTP_VERSION: 'HTTP/1.1',
        HTTP_HOST: 'carzar.herokuapp.com',
        HTTP_CONNECTION: 'close',
        HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: '1',
        HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
        HTTP_ACCEPT: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
        HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        HTTP_COOKIE: '_hjIncludedInSample=1; _ga=GA1.3.1023727724.1471250148; _website_session=Uzl4cVdsbzk4dEkxK0E5VFJxdWhHQmNJQVpHenNCdThuYkRFUERPNFhJNktzVHpKMlM0NzJlSEZFQmFGTUFwTXFLMDFySVh0Tnl1MjhEZzBrcUF0YTJmdXVzUE1ac3ltNG0ySDkxNlpIN2J2SDNQdmJYL0ZFS2Y3U1N0SEdOZTB1NnNOZGlrVm95SHdZSy93cGtCYW5nPT0tLW9zSERCSWgyNGdiMGw5VnZ0eTExR2c9PQ%3D%3D--0eecd3ec3784b2e82c65a09c677eac1c1482bfda',
        HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID: 'c270acca-988f-4f14-86a9-2ce4c8abacce',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: '196.22.246.146',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO: 'https',
        HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT: '443',
        HTTP_VIA: '1.1 vegur',
        HTTP_CONNECT_TIME: '0',
        HTTP_X_REQUEST_START: '1476952864670',
        HTTP_TOTAL_ROUTE_TIME: '0' } },
  session:
   { 
       session_id: '29e60f46d03a58702d3aada65c860482',
     _csrf_token: 'uF90eNX/nyVS72rEgM9ZNmGOJj4ad7gb35SKM941egs=' },
  params:

   { controller: 'quotes',
     action: 'show',
     car_id: '58079b9e918120003d678ef',
     id: '580759cae918120003d678f0',
     time: '2016-10-20T08:41:05.111Z' },
        name: "third",
        thingy: 3
}

    ];






  }
]);
```

how i can use the http service to read my json file data

Comment: Use $q API, create a deferred resolve, return the promise from the success function.  and use $http.get().success(function(data){//use $q, create a deferred resolve, return the promise from the success function}).then(function(data){vm.data = data // the data should be resolved promise from the success}).  refer [this](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http) and [this](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: are you getting any response in the success promise, did you display the value using alert

Comment: Try to see the error in the console in the debugger

Comment: i found that my error not from me its from the deepstream API json data which is coming to me till now i still dont know what iam gonna do.

Answer (score 0):

In your `http.get` call, the `this` context is different from the controller's `this`. Remove the `var vm = this` that is inside of your `$http.get` and keep it at the top of your controller function.

Change your request to point to

```
// Keep your reference to vm outside of the $http.get
var vm = this;
$http.get('data.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        // note that response here contains entire response. So if you want data only, you'll need to call response.data
        vm.data = response.data;
    });
```

Comment: still i get the same error : angular.js:11655SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 10
    at qc (angular.js:1072)
    at Zb (angular.js:8618)
    at angular.js:8703
    at r (angular.js:323)
    at Zc (angular.js:8702)
    at c (angular.js:9428)
    at angular.js:13248
    at n.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at n.$digest (angular.js:14282)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:14571)

Comment: Your json is most likely not formatted properly. Is this json being generated by code or did you do it manually?

Comment: no its coming from a https://deepstream.io/ api so i just took a result and i am trying to see how i can present it

Comment: can you console.log(response.data) and write some of it here

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EA2DCW9sCvLNrzucSC0o?p=preview  thank you john for helping me trying to solve this . please check my http://plnkr.co/edit/EA2DCW9sCvLNrzucSC0o?p=preview  plnkr

Comment: @HeshamElMasry No problem. Your json is invalid. It appears like you pasted your js object into a json file. JS objects are not valid json. For one, key names must be surrounded by double quotes.